# How to post an image to twitter from c# (unity)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, twitter

I'm trying to post an image to twitter from my unity application.

My goal is to let the player tweet an image to their tweeter account.

I tried

```
Application.OpenURL("http://twitter.com/intent/tweet/?text=a message to be tweeted");
```

This is perfect because the players will have to enter their username and password in their own browser.
but I want to add an image as well.

I Tried to change the

> ?text=

to

> ?media=

I have seen in a website that twitter accepts an "media" parameter but since `Application.OpenURL("");` accepts string, I couldn't pass byte[] of the image that I want to post to this URL to see whether it works or not.

I used `Convert.ToBase64String(byte[] data)` but for some reason, the `Application.OpenURL("");` doesn't work with it. i assume it's because the length of the string that i made from the byte[] becomes so long.

I also searched google a lot for ways to login to twitter or post an image but they're mostly using third-party libararies and most of answers that are look good are written in asp mvc not unity.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Reading their documentation, if you WANT to pass the media as a string, use `media_data` instead of `media`.  You will need to look online for how to convert the byte[] to a Base64 string.

https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/media/upload-media/api-reference/post-media-upload

Also, you will need to specify the `media_category` to let Twitter know that it is a `tweet_image`.

Comment: amm.. i actually don't get it
is media_data the name of the parameter that i need to pass through the link that i mentioned? other than that, the "https://upload.twitter.com/1.1/media/upload.json" only accepts the requests that are authenticated, and i don't know how to to that.

Comment: It wasn't clear to me that you only wanted to use web intents.  From what I can see in their documentation, there is no `media` parameter. https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-for-websites/tweet-button/guides/web-intent  What website did you read that said it did?

Comment: so it seems I was wrong, or I confused two things together.

lets forget it, how do you think I can achieve this goal? do you have any link or know any tutorial that can help me authenticate the user then post an image?
if you do, I'd like you ask you to please share that with me.
The developer docs of twitter is confusing for me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Web authentication is pretty much standard across most popular social media like Twitter, Facebook, Twitch, etc.  I don't have a tutorial or link, but you should probably start googling or watching YouTube videos related to "rest api authentication basics" or "oauth" topics with regards to C#. If you're the only one using this code, you can get away with hardcoding a username/password, but if not you'll want to find a more robust solution.